# How to measure download speed?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm struggling in how to properly calculate the download speed of a file using `C++` and `Qt`.

What I currently have:

```cpp
class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QByteArray downloadedData;
    QElapsedTimer downloadTimer;

    FileDownloader(const QUrl &url)
    {
        manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        QNetworkRequest request(url);
        QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request);
  
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, [=]
        {
            downloadedData.append(reply->readAll());

            if (!downloadTimer.isValid())
                downloadTimer.start();
        });

        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, [this](qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes)
        {
            int perc = 0;
            if (totalBytes)
                perc = static_cast<int>((bytesRead * 100) / totalBytes);

            qDebug().nospace() << "\n" << perc << "% (" << bytesRead << "/" << totalBytes << ")";

            qint64 elapsedMilliseconds = downloadTimer.elapsed();
            if (elapsedMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                double speedBytesPerSec = bytesRead / (elapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0); // Convert milliseconds to seconds
                double speedKbps = speedBytesPerSec * 8 / 1000;                       // Convert bytes to kilobits
                double speedMbps = speedKbps / 1000;                                  // Convert kilobits to megabits

                QString speedUnit;
                double speedValue;

                if (speedMbps >= 1.0)
                {
                    speedUnit = "MB/s";
                    speedValue = speedMbps;
                }
                else
                {
                    speedUnit = "KB/s";
                    speedValue = speedKbps;
                }

                qDebug().noquote() << "Download Speed:" << QString::number(speedValue, 'f', 2) << speedUnit;
            }
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QUrl url(
        "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=2208844&clcid=0x409&culture=en-us&country=US");
    FileDownloader fileDownloader(url);  

    return a.exec();
}
```

The code is compilable, and it's "working", the problem is the download speed being reported.

I'm not getting how to properly calculate it, on my attempt it looks like the value is increasing with time instead of reporting the real download speed.

obs: the `QUrl` in the code refers to an `.iso` file from [this Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-10-enterprise) (it's just a random file to debug the speed).

Comment: Please show the output speeds and explain what you expect them to be

Comment: @AlanBirtles hi, i have provided more info on the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the speed based on the total number of bytes that have been downloaded over the total time the download has been running. That only gets you an average speed at best.

The correct way to calculate the speed in real time is to calculate it based on however many bytes have been downloaded in just the current progress event (ie current `bytesRead` minus previous `bytesRead`) over however much time has elapsed since the previous progress event occured.

Speed can fluctuate during a network download, it is rarely ever constant.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QByteArray downloadedData;
    QElapsedTimer downloadTimer;
    qint64 prevBytesRead;

    FileDownloader(const QUrl &url)
    {
        manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        QNetworkRequest request(url);
        QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request);
  
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, [=]
        {
            if (!downloadTimer.isValid())
            {
                prevBytesRead = 0;
                downloadTimer.start();
            }

            downloadedData.append(reply->readAll());
        });

        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [=]
        {
            downloadTimer.invalidate();
        });

        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, [this](qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes)
        {
            int perc = 0;
            if (totalBytes > 0)
                perc = static_cast<int>((bytesRead * 100) / totalBytes);

            qDebug().nospace() << "\n" << perc << "% (" << bytesRead << "/" << totalBytes << ")";

            qint64 elapsedMilliseconds = downloadTimer.elapsed();
            if (elapsedMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                qint64 bytesReadThisTime = bytesRead - prevBytesRead;

                double speedBytesPerSec = bytesReadThisTime / (elapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0); // Convert milliseconds to seconds
                double speedKbps = speedBytesPerSec / 1024;                       // Convert bytes to kilobits
                double speedMbps = speedKbps / 1024;                                  // Convert kilobits to megabits

                QString speedUnit;
                double speedValue;

                if (speedMbps >= 1.0)
                {
                    speedUnit = "MB/s";
                    speedValue = speedMbps;
                }
                else if (speedKbps >= 1.0)
                {
                    speedUnit = "KB/s";
                    speedValue = speedKbps;
                }
                else
                {
                    speedUnit = "B/s";
                    speedValue = speedBytesPerSec;
                }

                qDebug().noquote() << "Download Speed:" << QString::number(speedValue, 'f', 2) << speedUnit;

                prevBytesRead = bytesRead;
                downloadTimer.restart();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: No need for `prevElapsedMilliseconds`, just call `reset` on the timer. This'll produce a very noisy output, if you're going to try to show instantaneous speeds you'll probably want to do some form of moving average

Comment: @AlanBirtles good point about the timer. As for displaying the speed, I would opt to simply not display it on every single event, but on more even multiples of time, like only once a second, even if there are multiple events within a second.

Comment: You use capital B to mean bytes in `"B/s"` and bits in `"KB/s"` and `"MB/s"`. Lowercase b should be used in the latter case to mean bits. Also, since you divide by 1024, that's now kibi-/mebibits, not kilo-/megabits.

Comment: `QElapsedTimer` doesn't have `.reset()`. I wonder if calling [.start()](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/c81e31461fd5a5bd2fe959f26b2e6d134b9a71e9/src/corelib/kernel/qelapsedtimer.cpp#L226) again would be the same as a "reset"? This is the [download speed](https://pastebin.com/F6ESB3U5) i get by replacing `downloadTimer.reset()` to `downloadTimer.start();` and this is the [download speed](https://pastebin.com/iZKYqqm2) using your code and just commenting `downloadTimer.reset();`. I have a 300MB fiber internet, when i download the same file using `Chrome` it reports 30~40 MB/s

Comment: @nina https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qelapsedtimer.html#restart, chrome will be reporting bytes per second, you're calculating bits per second